# autocannon requests sent to node server responded with non http response

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I am using autocannon to use load test my node api's but when I request 500 connections, 1500 total requests using autocannon then some requests are respond with - - ms to my server console.

When maximum load occurs then this problem comes and when I try with 1, 10 and 100, 150 connections to load test then works fine.

GET /web/user/plans - - ms - -
GET /web/user/plans - - ms - -
GET /web/user/plans 200 6227.062 ms - 697
GET /web/user/plans 200 6156.847 ms - 697
GET /web/user/plans 200 6157.383 ms - 697
some respond correctly but some like this - - ms.

I tried many times by searching to google and this still comes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.